Local notification does not light up the phone when is locked on android <14
I am trying to show a local notification on scheduled time, the problem is that if the phone is locked the notification will come, but I can't see it, till I touch my phone because it does not light up when it comes. This happens only on android below android 14, on android 14 works perfectly. How to fix this?
I was suggested to use WAKE_LOCK permission but that is not a good recommandation, since it takes all the battery of the phone.
This is my worker that checks the time when to show the notification.
class ReminderWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        if (AppPreferences.userNotifications && AppPreferences.specialUserNotifications) {
            AppPreferences.selectedDays.fromPrettyJson<ArrayList<String>>().forEach {
                val nextNotificationTime = calculateInitialDelay(
                    it.toInt(),
                    AppPreferences.hourOfDay,
                    AppPreferences.minuteOfDay
                )

                val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                val dayOfMonth = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                if (nextNotificationTime && dayOfMonth != AppPreferences.lastDayOfNotification) {
                    AppPreferences.lastDayOfNotification = dayOfMonth
                    triggerNotification()
                    WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).cancelUniqueWork("unique_work")

                } else {
                    scheduleNextWork()
                }

            }
        }
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun calculateInitialDelay(
        dayOfWeek: Int,
        hourOfTheDay: Int,
        minuteOfTheDay: Int
    ): Boolean {
        val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val notificationCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val calendarDayOfWeek = when (dayOfWeek) {
            1 -> Calendar.MONDAY
            2 -> Calendar.TUESDAY
            3 -> Calendar.WEDNESDAY
            4 -> Calendar.THURSDAY
            5 -> Calendar.FRIDAY
            6 -> Calendar.SATURDAY
            7 -> Calendar.SUNDAY
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of week: $dayOfWeek")
        }

        notificationCalendar.apply {
            set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendarDayOfWeek)
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfTheDay)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfTheDay)
            set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
        }
        val notificationEndCalendar = currentCalendar.clone() as Calendar
        notificationEndCalendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 3)

        // Convert to Date objects
        val currentDate = currentCalendar.time
        val notificationStartDate = notificationCalendar.time
        val notificationEndDate = notificationEndCalendar.time
        return notificationStartDate in currentDate..notificationEndDate
    }


    private fun scheduleNextWork() {
        val uniqueWorkName = "unique_work"
        val existingWorkPolicy = ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE
        val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ReminderWorker>()
            .setInitialDelay(10, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
            .enqueueUniqueWork(uniqueWorkName, existingWorkPolicy, workRequest)
    }


    private fun triggerNotification() {
        val notificationId = Random().nextInt(60000)

        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val channelId =
            App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name =
                App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val descriptionText =
                App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_notification_channel_name)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
                enableLights(true)
                enableVibration(true)

                if (defaultSoundUri != null) {
                    val att = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .build()
                    setSound(defaultSoundUri, att)
                }

                lightColor = Color.parseColor("#501450")
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val newIntent = Intent(applicationContext, StartActivity::class.java)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        newIntent.action = "actionString" + System.currentTimeMillis()
        val pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                applicationContext,
                0,
                newIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)//a resource for your custom small icon
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#222831"))
            .setContentText(App.instance.applicationContext.getString(R.string.remiderNotificationText))//ditto
            .setAutoCancel(true) //dismisses the notification on click
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(LongArray(0))
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)   // heads-up
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) // Ensure visibility on lock screen
            .setLights(Color.parseColor("#501450"), 3000, 3000)

        notificationManager.notify(
            notificationId /* ID of notification */,
            notificationBuilder.build()
        )
    }
}


Have you enabled lockscreen notifications  for your app on the Android device?

Yes, I enabled the lockscreen notifications on my settings
